# How do I update the address on a patent I own?

Tags: international

In reference to the patent: [US5504946](https://www.google.com/patents/US5504946)

I own this patent and would like to know how to update my UK address details. I do not have a lawyer.

What steps should I take to update my address with the USPTO?

Answer (score 2):

You can open a EFS-WEB account in [USPTO online filing system](http://www.uspto.gov/patents-application-process/file-online). This account requires you to have digital certificate which can be obtained freely from [USPTO LINK](https://dcm.uspto.gov/UserRegistration/do/Home) also read [HELP](http://www.uspto.gov/patents-application-process/applying-online/getting-started-new-users)

to know more about How to file address change request you can visit [USPTO help Presentation](http://www.uspto.gov/sites/default/files/ebc/portal/efs/cbt/efs-web-training.ppt).